# How to write PHP file to update database without ID or name?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to writing php file and are currently trying to create a database which stores heart rate measured together with the timestamp.

However I got confused how should I write for the update php file. Anyone knows how to write it given my situation where my

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE `User` SET timestamp = ?, heartrate = ?, WHERE ***what to include here*** = ?"); // I am not sure what to include here.
```

[image]

Code of my store data in database:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("server27.000webhost.com" , "a6244607_history" , "123" , "a6244607_history");



$timestamp = $_POST["timestamp"];
$heartrate = $_POST["heartrate"];




$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `User` (timestamp, heartrate) VALUES (?, ?) ");


mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $timestamp, $heartrate);


mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);



mysqli_stmt_close($statement);



mysqli_close($con);?>
```

Code to fetch data from database:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("server27.000webhost.com" , "a6244607_history" , "123" , "a6244607_history");


$timestamp = $_POST["timestamp"];

$heartrate = $_POST["heartrate"];



$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE timestamp = ? AND heartrate = ?");


mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $timestamp, $heartrate);


mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);



mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);


mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $timestamp, $heartrate);



$user = array();



while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement))
{

    $user[timestamp] = $timestamp;

    $user[heartrate] = $heartrate;

}



echo json_encode($user);



mysqli_stmt_close($statement);



mysqli_close($con);?>
```

Code to update database:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("server27.000webhost.com" , "a6244607_history" , "123" , "a6244607_history");



$timestamp = $_POST["timestamp"];

$heartrate = $_POST["heartrate"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE `User` SET timestamp = ?, heartrate = ?, WHERE username = ?");


mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $timestamp, $heartrate);


mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);



mysqli_stmt_close($statement);



mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

On a side note, is my timestamp written correctly? Sorry for asking so much questions at once...

Hope to get some help soon, thank you.

Comment: Why is android tagged....?

Comment: Could you please explain what's your problem exactly? what do you want to fetch from the database?

Comment: @EnsiehParsaeian I am not sure about how to write this sentence for update: 
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE `User` SET timestamp = ?, heartrate = ?, WHERE ***what to include here*** = ?"); 

As previously for my update I wrote it like that:
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE `User` SET timestamp = ?, heartrate = ?, WHERE username = ?");

Any idea how to change because now i do not have a field for it to look for to update... Sorry if my explanation is no good..

Comment: @Razgriz because i am doing this with android studio... new to stack overflow sorry...

Comment: Use the primary key of the table in the where clause or else a column with unique value. If username is PK or unique, you can use it.

Comment: To get timestamp, use time() function instead of trying to read it from form. time() returns Unix time stamp for current time.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should not include credentials to your MySQL server on the post

2) Considering you only have 3 tables (user_id, heartrate, timestamp) and in this Prepared Statement:

```
UPDATE `User` SET timestamp = ?, heartrate = ?, WHERE ***what to include here*** = ?
```

You use timestamp and heart rate, so for ***what to include here*** should be user_id.
If you want to insert a brand new heart rate, use INSERT instead of SET.

Also, your statement should look like:

```
UPDATE `User` SET `timestamp` = ?, `heartrate` = ?, WHERE `user_id` = ?
```

Use the grave (`) around table names.